# multiple postback events in an update panel

Tags: jquery, updatepanel

I have an update panel containing several divs which utilize jquery ui's draggable. On drag stop i want to do a postback which only effects the update panel.

This works fine, but before continuing down this road i was wondering if a second divs dragstop event occured during a previous divs postback would both postbacks be executed properly?

Thanks in advance,

shawn

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question, but I think that it would be faily easy to test if you get one or two postbacks by setting a breakpoint in `Page_Load()` and the debug the page to see if you get one or two postbacks.